# Spring Security custom HTML login page not recognised using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

i have followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoTohM2jYhs) for all configurations to set link up my custom html page for login. However, when i access localhost/login, i am faced with error status 500.

I am unable to render a simple html page when I access localhost:8080/login.

1. Are there extra configurations needed?
2. Should the html page be located at templates folder? How does the application know it should render "login.html" ?
3. Is my controller being recognised?

config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();

    }

}
```

controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

replacing "login" above with below also shows error.

```html
<h1> Login page <h1>
```

dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

login.html is located in templates.
error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

My folder hierachy:
[image]

Comment: replace `@Controller `by `@RestController`

Comment: can you add abit more explanation why this should work? 
I have tried changing Controller to RestController, and get no error, but i do not get the html page i want as well. Are there extra configurations needed then?

Comment: I have added my answer. Please mark it as an acceptable answer as it resolved your error.

Comment: No, this did not resolve my error.

Comment: you have mentioned that you have got no error. you are not getting resource files on your page because you have not permitted those.

Comment: is the use of thymeleaf not resolving this?

Comment: I have already answered your qs. see that. you must have to add that configuration.

Comment: I would like to add that apart from thymeleaf dependency, there is no need to add those configuration if you are using thymeleaf to avoid any confusion for those referencing this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RestController` is a composed annotation that is itself meta-annotated with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` indicating a controller whose every method inherits the type-level `@ResponseBody` annotation and therefore writes directly to the response body vs view resolution and rendering with an HTML template.

That's why I advised replacing `@Controller` by `@RestController`.

You will not get static resources in your html file. to get this you have to add this.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above and am still facing internal server error code 500.

Comment: If i replace Controller with @RestController, i am making no reference to my custom html page. Are there other things that I would need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Its behaving as if it cant find your controller. Did you put it in the same package as the main class or deeper in the hierachy?

The component scan which looks for the controller annotation scans from the package your main class is in and beneath it. If you put the controller further out in your folder hierachy it isnt found.

Comment: i think it is recognizing the controller class properly, but not the static html page.

If i add a simple system.out.println before return "login", i see the statement getting printed.

Comment: Im trying to reproduce the error but I cant. 
If I remove the controller I get at 404 not found. 
If I remove only the html and keep the controller I get a template not found.
If I add both it works

Comment: is your html file also located in src/main/resources/templates?

Comment: Yes. 
Ok so if I remove the thymeleaf dependency I can reproduce it because without it you will get the cyclic error because the html file and the controller mapping is using the same name. Could you try to run mvn clean install to make sure the thymeleaf dependencies are added.
When thymeleaf is there it should work because then it finds the html file.
To test it you can also try to rename the login html to login2.html and change the text you return in the controller to login2

Comment: I have added my folder hierarchy.  I ran mvn clean install and renaming the html and controller return string to another name and am getting 404 now. 

I get error code 500 when i use login as the return string and login.html as the file name, and error code 404 when i use login2 as the return string and login2.html as the file name.

Comment: Ok so now your not hitting your controller either? thats a little odd unless you also renamed the mapping.
The controller should look like this now
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login2";
    }
}

Comment: Yes, that is the same as the one i've posted above.

Comment: Im not very sure if it is the controller class which is causing the problem. If i add a system.out.println("TEST"); before return "login"; , i do see that TEST statement being printed in console when i visit localhost:8080/login.

Comment: If you changed your html file to login2.html then you also have to return login2 in the controller. Otherwise it cant find the template.

Comment: Yeah, i did change both the filename of my html file and the string name returned from my controller for all cases mentioned above.

Comment: Is it just a sample your working on? then perhaps you could share it on github so I could take a look at the code? that would be alot easier =)

Comment: have you checked my folder hierarchy above and can confirm it is ok?

Comment: even if i delete my html file from the templates folder, i never get any "template not found", but always only internal server error status code 500

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have managed to resolved the error but was not conclusive of the cause of it.
The ultimate fix was to keep the mapping url to "/login" in the LoginController and SecurityConfiguration files, and to changed the naming of my html and thymeleaf's references of it in my controller file and html file name as per below.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login2() {
        return "login2";
    }
}
```

The main reason I would believe has been causing this is because my application and package name were also named "login" which made thymeleaf unable to refer to the right file properly. I have selected the answer above as best answer for others who faced the issue due to different reasons to try out the same experiment to obtain their useful result.